# How to apply filter only if nested mapping exists

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to apply location radius on nested ES query but the nested value is not present all the time causing exception

```
"[nested] nested object under path [contact.address] is not of nested type"
```

I tried to check if the property exists then apply filter but nothing worked so far

The mapping is like:

```
{
  "records": {
    "mappings": {
      "user": {
        "properties": {
          "user_id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "contact": {
            "properties": {
              "address": {
                "properties": {
                  "city": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "location": {
                    "properties": {
                      "lat": {
                        "type": "long"
                      },
                      "lng": {
                        "type": "long"
                      },
                      "lon": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
              },
              "email": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "properties": {
                  "first_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "last_name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "created_at": {
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and sometimes the records do not have the location or address data which cases problems. sample record:

```
{
   "contact": {
      "name": {
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "User"
       },
        "email": "test@user.com",
        "address": {}
    },
    "user_id": 532188
}
```

here is what i'm trying:

```
GET records/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "contact.address"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "contact.address.location"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "nested": {
                "ignore_unmapped": true,
                "path": "contact.address",
                "query": {
                  "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "50mi",
                    "contact.address.location": {
                      "lat": 51.5073509,
                      "lon": -0.1277583
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like you are using old version of ES, May i know which one? also you have not defined your contact field as `nested` but using it as `nested.path` in your query

Comment: yes, it is version 6.3

Comment: Updated my comment, please check that as well, while I am working on to provide solution :)

Comment: i guess the mapping was auto generated around 2 years ago and worked till yesterday when started throwing error

Comment: did you update your ES from when this mapping was generated also, I can provide the right way to dealing with this, but it would require to change your mapping and re-index the data, as that's the standard way of dealing with nested object, let me know if that's fine for you

Comment: no the ES was setup using ELK docker and since then it was never changed. i thought the issue could be handled using some filter query but if re-indexing is the only way to go then i'll create new mapping and index data using nodejs. your help suggesting the right mapping greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211274/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-raza-ahmed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define proper mapping with `nested` datatype to avoid this issue, looks dynamic mapping is creating some issue.

**I defined my own mapping with `nested` datatype and even when I miss, some data in the nested fields, it doesn't complain.**

### Index def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "user_id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "contact": {
                "type": "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index sample doc

```
{
   "contact": {
      "name": {
        "first_name": "raza",
        "last_name": "ahmed"
       },
        "email": "opster@user.com",
        "address" :{ --> note empty nested field
        }

    },
    "user_id": 123456
}
```

### Index another doc with data in the nested field

```
{
   "contact": {
      "name": {
        "first_name": "foo",
        "last_name": "bar"
       },
        "email": "opster@user.com",
        "address": {
            "location" :{. --> note nested data as well
                "lat" : 51.5073509,
                "lon" : -0.1277583
            }
        }
    },
    "user_id": 123456
}
```

### Index another doc, which doesn't have even empty `nested` data

```
{
   "contact": {
      "name": {
        "first_name": "foo",
        "last_name": "bar"
       },
        "email": "opster@user.com"
    },
    "user_id": 123456
}
```

### Search query using `nested` field

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "contact", --> note this
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "contact.address"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "exists": {
                                "field": "contact.name.first_name"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### The search result doesn't complain about the docs which don't include the nested doc (query which gives you issues)

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "nested",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 2.0,
        "_source": {
          "contact": {
            "name": {
              "first_name": "foo",
              "last_name": "bar"
            },
            "email": "opster@user.com",
            "address": { --> note the nested doc
              "location": {
                "lat": 51.5073509,
                "lon": -0.1277583
              }
            }
          },
          "user_id": 123456
        }
      }
```